# Use reference to sub object in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView control on my ASPX page. It works fine until i try to get a certain property from my object list.

I insert an object like this in a list:

```
var test = new List<DataTest>
{
    new DataTest
        {
            Name = "A name",
            Bla = new Bla()
        }
}
```

The class `Bla` looks like this:

```
public class Bla
{
    public string Blaat = "aaa";
}
```

But it seems i'm not able to get the property `Blaat` in a GridView, like this:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Bla.Blaat" HeaderText="Name" />
```

I can however output `Name` with no problem:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
```

Does this mean i can only use properties that are *directly* defined in the `DataTest` object? So no reference to any *sub* object, like `Bla.Blaat` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use a TemplateField:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblName" Text='<%# Server.HtmlEncode(Convert.ToString(Eval("Bla.Blaat"))) %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

You could also set the value in the code-behind.